# Can I use EF Core 2.0 'AsNoTracking' in CRUD service GetAll?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I have an Application Service that implements:

```
public interface IPracticeAppService : IAsyncCrudAppService<PracticeDto, int, PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto,CreatePracticeDto, PracticeDto>
```

I would like to use [`AsNoTracking`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.asnotracking?view=efcore-2.0).

In the example below, is there a way of using `AsNoTracking`?

```
public override Task<PagedResultDto<PracticeDto>> GetAll(PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto input)
{    
    return base.GetAll(input);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. However, `.AsNoTracking()` only applies to `IQueryable` so you can't call the `base` method.

```cs
public override async Task<PagedResultDto<PracticeDto>> GetAll(PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto input)
{
    CheckGetAllPermission();

    var query = CreateFilteredQuery(input).AsNoTracking(); // Here!

    var totalCount = await AsyncQueryableExecuter.CountAsync(query);

    query = ApplySorting(query, input);
    query = ApplyPaging(query, input);

    var entities = await AsyncQueryableExecuter.ToListAsync(query);

    return new PagedResultDto<PracticeDto>(
        totalCount,
        entities.Select(MapToEntityDto).ToList()
    );
}
```